# Strange Array Error

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Running the following code in Java gives me a "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 215737344"

But the S.O.P statements prints "215737344"
Why are the loops continuing if they should be done?

```
public static final int DICE_SIDE_LENGTH = 16;

static int width = 9792;
static int height = 7344;

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
    byte[] imageArray = new byte[width * height * 3];
    int image_at=0;
    System.out.println((height/DICE_SIDE_LENGTH) * DICE_SIDE_LENGTH * (width/DICE_SIDE_LENGTH) * 16 *3 );
    for(int row = 0; row<height/DICE_SIDE_LENGTH; row++){
        int[] diceArray = new int[width/DICE_SIDE_LENGTH];  
        for(int p=0; p<DICE_SIDE_LENGTH; p++){
            for(int die: diceArray){
                byte[] dice_row = new byte[16];
                for(int i=0; i<dice_row.length; i++){
                    imageArray[i + image_at]=dice_row[i];
                    imageArray[i + image_at+ 1]=dice_row[i];
                    imageArray[i + image_at + 2]=dice_row[i];
                    image_at+=3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `array[array.length]` is always out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<dice_row.length; i++){
   if(image_at<(width * height *3){
          imageArray[image_at]=dice_row[i];
          imageArray[image_at+ 1]=dice_row[i];
          imageArray[image_at + 2]=dice_row[i];
          image_at+=3;
                    }
```

Do you really need that `i` in there? I think this should work if you want to add the same byte every 3 cells in `imageArray`. The `if` check is there because I'm frankly a bit confused by your loops. You could probably remove it if you're sure `image_at` won
t go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Size of your `imageArray` is `215737344`

But you are trying to access index 215737344 inside your `for loop`.

Change your code as shown below, and try to debug:

```
                    int i = 0;
                    try {
                        for(i=0; i<dice_row.length; i++){
                            imageArray[i + image_at]=dice_row[i];
                            imageArray[i + image_at+ 1]=dice_row[i];
                            imageArray[i + image_at + 2]=dice_row[i];
                            image_at+=3;
                        }
                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception");
                    }
```